# How to communicate to an inventory item which character it's being used on?

Tags: unity, c#, gui, software-engineering, inventory

Currently, I have an `Inventory` that is a `ScriptableObject`, which means it's not tied to any specific game object or player character. I just drag it into a `MonoBehaviour` if I would like expose the data of the inventory.

I have created an `InventoryUI`, which is a `MonoBehaviour` attached to a `GameObject` in my scene, and I assign the `Inventory` SO to it.

The `InventoryUI` contains button `GameObjects` with an `InventorySlot` script, to which I assign the item each slot is holding.

Everything works fine. When I click on one of the `InventorySlot` buttons, I'm able to call item methods, such as `UseItem`.

My problem is if the the item is a potion, for example. **How can i add health to the player?** Of course I could add reference to the player to the slot. But that will reference player repeatedly over 25 slots.

Comment: What about using triggerEvents on your inventory slot sprites? hook them up to a method that want to execute on use.

Comment: Can you provide any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Myself, I'd let the `InventoryUI` script own the interaction with the inventory.

When a player opens the `InventoryUI`, you call something like `InventoryUI.ShowInventoryFor(PlayerCharacter character)`.

This procedure handles any initial setup of the menu (populating the slots, etc.) and caches the character it was given as its `currentUser` member variable.

Each of the UI buttons on the menu is wired up to call `InventoryUI.UseItemInSlot(int slotID)` when clicked. That centralizes all of the item use actions onto the one script that knows who's using the menu.

Now the `InventoryUI` can fetch the corresponding item in your inventory structure, and call `inventoryItem.UseItemOn(currentUser)`, passing its knowledge of who is using the item through to the function that performs the item's action.

Finally, that item receives a reference to the character it should modify - by giving it more health, etc.

Doing it this way, you might not need your `InventorySlot` script at all. The buttons in the menu can be just plain buttons, with the knowledge of the meaning behind each button provided by the `InventoryUI` itself.

Comment: Thank you sir, this made it more clear how i should set it up